# netplan switch connection on renderer networkd

Tags: networking, vpn, netplan, systemd-networkd

I have installed on rpi4 8Gb an ubuntu 20.04 server image for rpi4 64Bit

then I have installed **ubuntu-desktop**

I have problem on wifi and setup this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi/+bug/1897942)

I have disable NetworkManager thinking the pakage have some bug

I have to stay on LTS version 20.04 so if it work on 20.10 I have to wait a backport

I configure netplan to use networkd as renderer.

I future I have to configure vpn.

I have not found maual/help/google on how to change connection.
On NetworkManager I can setup 4 connection for example

1. conn1 using dhcp
2. conn2 using fix IP for test
3. conn3 using wifi
4. con4  using a vpn

then I can choose the connection to use.
close connection 1 ad open connection 2 etc.

How con do this on my configuration using netplan, systemd-networkd?

best regards,
Leonardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found documentation:
[netplan faq](https://netplan.io/faq/#bring-interfaces-up-or-down)
so to see internet connection name devices you can do:
`$ ip a`

and so to turn off and on mine wifi internet connection
`ip link set wlan0 down`
`ip link set wlan0 up`

this is usefull too: [network-configuration](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration)

best regards,
Leonardo